# 2 click social media buttons for non-Wordpress pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, social-networking

Does anyone know if this script for 2-click social media buttons is available for non-Wordpress pages to are knows a similar script, pure jQuery?

Here is the Link: [2-click social media buttons](http://wordpress.org/plugins/2-click-socialmedia-buttons/)

Thank you

Comment: That plugin has a lot of features, what are the main features you need for your non-wordpress website?

Comment: Actually just the basic function which: the click option/activation and deactivation for the social plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There are many versions of this plugin.

The original one was [`socialshareprivacy`](https://www.heise.de/extras/socialshareprivacy/) and was created to comply with the German laws. It's a jQuery plugin but all it's documentation is in German.

Some forks have been released later, including [SocialSharePrivacy](https://panzi.github.io/SocialSharePrivacy/)
, another jQuery plugin.

Some [other forks](https://www.heise.de/extras/socialshareprivacy/#forks) exists too but it should be enough for your needs.

Comment: It was a late answer!